# What's the best way to explain what the options in a drop down menu mean?

Tags: forms, dropdown, drop-down-list

Please see image below. The drop down I'm struggling with is the "permission level" drop down. Users won't be immediately familiar with what the different permission levels mean. In the screenshot, I've included the description of the level within the drop-down menu, but am wondering if there's a better way? I played with radio buttons but that made it more difficult to read horizontally - it made it harder to immediately see what permission level is associated to each school. Another thing to note is that the options within "permission level" can vary based on the school that's selected (3 options are the maximum).
Any help would me much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Your solution is reasonable: having descriptions users will pick correct level easily. Still pay attention of how the descriptions are formulated. It's better to use terms and concepts which are used by school, as they are familiar to users. Also +Add Permissions button looks confusing. Did you mean Add School?

Comment: For just three levels, I'd probably use radio button (or nicer equivalent), with heading and short descriptive text below. Lowest level pre-selected. No need to make it complex and a drop-down seems overkill. As always, IMHO, YMMV, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach seems fine to me. I'd just be a little more detailed and make sure what each level can and cannot do is amply clear. Something like this:

[image]

These could be visual indicators of each level, too (probably an icon?). Sorry about the typos in that mockup! :)